# c++ use cout in class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, io, iostream

I'm getting `cin` `cout` and `endl` as undeclared errors despite using `#include <iostream>`

```
#include "navigation.h"
#include <iostream>
Navigation::Navigation()
{
    xPos=0;
    yPos=0;
}
void Navigation::Move()
{
    //get direction
    int dir;
    cout << "Select a direction: " << endl;
    cout << "1) North    3) South" << endl;
    cout << "2) East     4) West " << endl;
    cin >> dir;
    //move
    switch(dir)
    {
    case 0://north
        yPos++;
        break;
    case 1://east
        xPos++;
        break;
    case 2://south
        yPos--;
        break;
    case 3://west
        xPos--;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
    }
}

void Navigation::Position(int &x, int &y)
{
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
}
```

Comment: prefix them with `std::` (good style) or use `using namespace std;` (bad style).

Comment: Try std::cout, std::endl, std::cin.  Or add a using namespace std; somewhere (after you includes is a nice place for it).

Comment: why is `using namespace` considered bad style?

Comment: @yamikoWebs Because of possible name clashes. All members of `std` namespace are now visible in global namespace.

Comment: @yamikoWebs see my updated answer for why `using namespace` isn't the first choice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are in the std namespace. Add these lines:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
```

Alternatively, each time you use them, call them by their full names, for example:

```
std::cout << "Select a direction: " << std::endl;
```

That gets tiresome very quickly and can make your code harder to read, too.

Some people use

```
using namespace std;
```

instead, but you may get unwanted side-effects from that. A class you have written may have the same name as something else in the std namespace and your over-broad using statement will now cause a collision. This is why you should NEVER say `using namespace std;` in a header file. In a .cpp file it's ok, but I prefer individual statements myself. It makes it clear to whoever reads your code what you are using from the headers you have included.

Comment: IMHO it makes it easier to read, using `std::` each time. Clearly demarcates standard library entities from things declared in your own code.

Answer (score 5):

They are members of the `std` namespace so you need to qualify them with `std`: `std::endl`, `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Answer (score 4):

Include `using namespace std;` after your `#include` statements.

Answer (score 1):

endl, cin and cout are in the namespace std.  You either need a `using namespace std;` near the top of your file, or to use `std::endl`, `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `using namespace std;` [after your `#include`s section] or use `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::endl`